# TransformException: duplicate entry for DoubleMetaphone.class Gradle error

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm getting the following error when I try to generate a signed APK file in Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphone.class

My Build.gradle is given below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    //    added for unicode encoding
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.example"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookActivity')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.4.3-core.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-1.4.3-s3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: I think you don't need to add this "libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar" instead of this you can directly add this  line useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' into android{}.

Comment: This error come due to "org.appache" library where tow library have same same class.

Comment: after adding useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' it solves the issue but now below error is occurred

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
          > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these lines of code inside `android{}`

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
```